# Recursively rename files by using a list of patterns and replacements

Tags: bash, rename, recursive

I have the following file structure:

- Some directory

  - Some file.txt
  - Another file here.log
  - Yet another file.mp3
- Another directory

  - With some other file.txt
- File on root level.txt
- Another file on root level.ext

What I want to do now is run a little script that takes another file as input containing some type of pattern/replacement pairs in it to rename these files recursively according to them. So that every "another" (case insensitive) gets replaced with "foo" or every "some" with "bar."

I already tried a lot of things with iterating over files and reading said input file, but nothing worked like it should and I finally managed to accidentally overwrite my testing script. But there were a lot of `ls`, `while`, `sed` or `mv` in use.

The two things I couldn't resolve myself were how to handle whitespace in filenames and how to not handle files that were already renamed in a previous pattern match.

Maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Whitespace doesn't work because you didn't put double quotes around variable substitutions (`"$foo"`). See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TOP="`pwd -P`" \
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   for d
   do
      cd "$d" && \
         find . ! -name . -prune -type f -exec sh -c '\''
            while IFS=\; read -r pat repl
            do
               rename "s/$pat/$repl/g" "$@"
               N=$#
               for unmoved
               do
                  if [ -f "$unmoved" ]
                  then
                     set X ${1+"$@"} "$unmoved"
                     shift
                  fi
               done
               shift "$N"
               case $# in 0 ) break ;; esac
            done < patterns.csv
         '\'' x \{\} +
      cd "$TOP"
   done
' x {} +
```

- Set up `find` to net directories only and have `sh` down them in a gulp. This minimizes the number of invocations of `sh`.
- Set up `find` in each of these directories to net `regular` files, at a depth level of 1 only, and feed them to `sh` in a gulp. This minimizes the number of times the `rename` utility gets to be called.
- Set up a `while` loop to read-in the various `pattern <-> replacement` pairs and apply them on all the `regular` files.
- In the process of `rename`-*ing* we keep a note on whether a file was still standing after the `rename` process. If we find that a file still exists then that means, for some reason, it could not be renamed and hence would be tried in the next `pat/repl` iteration. OTOH, if the file was successfully renamed, then we DONT apply the next `pat/repl` iteration on this file by taking it away from the command line arguments list.

Comment: I really got you thinking about a solution here :D
Your script works nearly flawlessly, except the warning `x: 4: cd: can't cd to ./Another directory` when letting it run on the file structure of my question. But the renaming took place nonetheless.

Comment: I've marked this as accepted answer, since I didn't think of performance beforehand and this is the much better script than my solution.

Comment: I never got down to testing this stuff at my end since was too lazy to setup a separate directory structure. All this was in my head only and hence the bug of `cd "$PWD"`. I have placed a fix for that now by passing the launch directory to `find`.

Comment: What is type of patterns that you have in your patterns.csv file? This will have a bearing on the `rename` utility's `s///` command behavior.

Comment: Now the scripts works flawlessly :) I tested the script now with the patterns `Another;foo`, `Some;bar` and `File on root level;Root level`. There won't be more "complicated" things like special characters or umlauts.

Answer (score 1):

```
rPairs="/tmp/rename_pairs" \
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
   while read -r old new; do
      rename "s/$old/$new/i" "$@"
   done < "$rPairs"
' x {} +
```

Assuming that there are no nonASCII characters in your rename pairs file and
also this file is placed away from the search path.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, though it would fail if the same file matches multiple patterns in the input file. But ultimately you brought me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

After Rakesh Sharma's answer I got in the right direction after experimenting a bit more and getting some sleep.

Finally I came up with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash


while IFS=";" read pattern replacement
do
  if [[ ! -z $pattern ]]
  then
    echo "Checking files for pattern '$pattern'."

    find ./files -name "*$pattern*" -type f | while read fpath
    do
      fname=$(basename "$fpath")
      dname=$(dirname "$fpath")

      echo "  Found file '$fname' in directory '$dname'. Renaming to '${fname/$pattern/$replacement}'."
      mv -- "$fpath" "$dname/${fname/$pattern/$replacement}"
    done
  fi
done < patterns.csv
```

It reads the file `pattern.csv` and loops over its lines filling the `$pattern` and `$replacement` variables In the second step all files within a directory `./files` are found, that match the current pattern. This has to be done to avoid trying to rename files again when a second pattern matches, since that would fail. Finally it only renames the file itself, not the directories containing it by using shell parameter substitution.

What's not working is replacing the matches case-insensitive, but I can live with that.

Comment: You need to realize that in the Unix-world, filenames are case-sensitive. So, what would happen if you were to rename in a case-insensitive manner, 2 different files, `foo.log` and `Foo.log` is that both would be mapped to `newname.log`, which you will surely agree is not a healthy situation to be in. I have posted another solution which hopefully ameliorates the situation and requires the presence of the `rename` utility written in `Perl`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That was something I learned the hard way when switching from development in Windows to Unix years ago. But now I only see the good parts of that :)

Answer (score 0):

The important point to keep in mind is that travesing through the directory tree is a slow process hence that is done only once. What we do is first make `find` look at only the directories in the tree. And foreach directory we go look for all `regular files` underneath them (no recursion here). We then apply the rename transformation on these filenames and at the same time keep a note on whether it succeeded or not. If successful, then we break out of the while loop thereby preventing the next patt/repl to be applied on this file.

```
tempd="`mktemp -d`" \
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   cd "$1" && \
   for f in ./*
   do
      [ -f "$f" ] || continue
      while IFS=\; read -r patt repl
      do
         case $f in
            ./*"$patt"* )
               rename -v "s/$patt/$repl/g" "$f" 2>&1 | tee "$tempd/$f"
               case $(< "$tempf/$f") in "$f renamed "* ) break ;; esac ;;
         esac
      done < /tmp/patterns.csv
   done
' {} {} \;
```

Comment: This scripts renames the files of the above file structure exactly as I want it, but a lot of warnings like `.: 11: .: cannot open /./Another file on root level.ext: No such file` get shown.